# Setting boundaries of Graph

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have a curve where the limits for approximation should be set. The question is, how do I find the left boundary: it is not a maximum and also not a bending point. It is supposed to be the relative "beginning" of the straight plateau as on graph (see below).

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijUvE.png)

I have set different filters for the search for critical points. Here are just two of them: Gaussian with 5 points window and Savitzky-Golay. These are only used to determine the critical points. As you can see, the critical points (in ellipse) did not land in the desired places. The left is the first stationary point (max or inflection point) and the right - again the falling inflection point or measuring point with Y=0.

Do you have any idea how I should proceed? Thank you in advance.